# Add route programmatically in C++ using ioctl

Tags: c++, linux, routes, ioctl

I've written simple C++ function, that adds new route:

```
void addRoute()
{
    int fd = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP );

    struct rtentry route;
    memset( &route, 0, sizeof( route ) );

    struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)&route.rt_gateway;
    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "192.168.20.1" );

    addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_dst;
    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "10.0.0.50" );

    addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_genmask;
    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    route.rt_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY;
    route.rt_metric = 0;

    int rc = ioctl( fd, SIOCADDRT, &route );
    cout << "rc = " << rc << endl; //rc = -1
    close( fd );
}

int main()
{
    addRoute();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is ioctl returns -1 (rc = -1). What is wrong with my code?
I launch it from **root**. I want to execute ip route and see this line:

```
10.0.0.50 via 192.168.20.1 dev vpn_linux
```

Comment: You should see what error code `errno` is being set to (Hint: Use `strerror()` or `perror()` to get a human-readable version, not a cryptic number).

Comment: @Shawn
hey, I used strerror(): "Invalid argument". Maybe I did not setup correctly struct rtentry route ?

Comment: I am able to add a route using a terminal and this command: 
sudo ip ro add 10.0.0.50 via 192.168.20.1

Answer (score 0):

You're masking with `INADDR_ANY` ([0.0.0.0](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html)) an address whose format is `a.b.c.d/32`, so it should use `255.255.255.255`.

The solution for /32 is:

```
addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_dst;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "10.0.0.50" );

addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_genmask;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "255.255.255.255" );
```