# How to add route programmatically in C using ioctl?

Tags: c, linux, routes, ioctl

I want to add some route to routing table. This command works perfectly from terminal:

```
sudo ip ro add 10.0.0.6 via 192.168.30.1
```

If I check "ip route", I see, that route was added.
I want to implement the same command in C using ioctl. I wrote this function:

```
void addRoute()
{
    int fd = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,  IPPROTO_IP);

    struct rtentry route;
    memset( &route, 0, sizeof( route ) );

    struct sockaddr_in addr = (struct sockaddr_in )&route.rt_gateway;
    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "10.0.0.6" );

    addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_dst;
    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "192.168.30.1" );

    addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_genmask;
    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    route.rt_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_HOST;
    route.rt_metric = 0;

    if (ioctl( fd, SIOCADDRT, &route ) < 0)
    {
        printf("ioctl failed and returned errno %s \n", strerror(errno));
    }
    close( fd );
}

int main()
{
    addRoute();
    return 0;
}
```

unfortunately, after executing I always see the error:

```
    ioctl failed and returned errno Network is unreachable
```

Could you review my code, please ? What have I forgotten to add to my function ?

Comment: Did you post [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57959731/9952196) earlier from a different account? Or just in the same class or something? Might want to compare notes.

Comment: @Shawn almost certainly the same person with 2 accounts, given that both names are from mashing the left hand's home row keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct sockaddr_in * addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&route.rt_gateway;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.30.1");

addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_dst;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.6");;

addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_genmask;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_NONE; //255.255.255.255
route.rt_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY;
//route.rt_metric = 0;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).